# Numerus des Verbs bei Aufzählungen im Prädikativ

Tags: verb, grammatical-number

Ich habe folgende Frage: Welchen Numerus würde ich für das Verb wählen bei folgendem Beispielsatz:

Erleben ist/sind unser Denken, unsere Gefühle.

Kommt es hier nur auf das Gefühl an, oder gibt es bei Aufzählungen im Prädikativ spezielle Regeln?

Answer (score 1):

Erstmal zu dem Fall "unsere Gefühle", ohne Aufzählung:

Aus Duden Grammatik 8. Auflage, Randnummer 1632:

> Wo [sich Subjekt und prädikativer Nominativ im Numerus unterscheiden], steht das finite Verb gewöhnlich im Plural.

Als Beispiele werden dort unter anderem genannt:

> Diese Sachen sind mein einziger Besitz.
> Das sind meine einzigen Ferien.
> Besonders Rechtschreibfehler waren ihm immer ein Gräuel.

Direkt zur Aufzählung bei Prädikativen finde ich da nichts, aber grundsätzlich stehen Aufzählungen im Subjekt ja mit einem Plural-Verb ("Messer, Gabel und Löffel gehören zum Tischbesteck."), deshalb wäre wohl auch hier der Plural angemessen.

> Erleben sind unser Denken, unsere Gefühle.

oder etwas klarer, mit *und*:

> Erleben sind unser Denken und unsere Gefühle.

Allerdings, wie @OranMatheus in den Kommentaren bemerkt, wird der Fall, dass das Subjekt im Singular und das Prädikativ im Plural steht, laut Duden Grammatik (RN 1579) "vermieden, ausgenommen bei Pronomen wie *es, das, welches*".

Man könnte, um das zu vermeiden, stattdessen das Verb in der jeweils richtigen Form wiederholen:

> Erleben ist unser Denken, sind unsere Gefühle.

Stilistisch gesehen frage ich mich aber auch, was "ist" oder "sind" in diesem Satz eigentlich für eine Bedeutung haben soll. Vielleicht wäre ein semantisch etwas stärkeres Verb wie *berührt*, *umfasst*, *betrifft*, *fordert* o.ä. auch eine Alternative, das wäre etwas aussagekräftiger und würde das Grammatik-Problem auch gleich mit lösen.

Comment: Randnummer 1579 erwähnt allerdings, dass Subjekt im Singular und präd. Nom. im Plural vermieden wird, außer einige der Pronomenen sind das Subjekt. In den Beispielsätzen ist kein Beispiel, das dem aus der Frage gleicht. "Erleben umfassen/sind ..." ist also vermutlich nicht richtig.

Comment: @OranMatheus Es heißt dann natürlich "Erleben umfasst", denn das Subjekt ist ja dann klar Singular, Der Beispielsatz, der grammatisch am ehersten dem aus der Frage entspricht, ist "Das sind meine einzigen Ferien."

Comment: Dann kann "Erleben ... sind unsere Gefühle", bei der Ellipse, auch nicht richtig sein, oder? Die beiden letzten Beispiele der Antwort meine ich damit.

Comment: @OranMatheus Der Unterscheid ist, dass es beim Verb "ist" Prädikative sind, die im Plural stehen, dann gilt das, was ich aus der Duden Grammatik zitiert habe. Bei "umfasst" werden die zu Objekten, dann spielt nur noch das Numerus des Subjekts eine Rolle.

Comment: Vielen Dank an alle. Ich sehe ein, dass der Satz an sich elliptisch ist und dementsprechend wahrscheinlich viele Gesetzmäßigkeiten nicht angewendet werden können. Trotzdem bin ich noch nicht ganz glücklich damit. Die genannten Beispiele sind ja vor allem Aufzählungen im Subjekt und nicht im Prädikativ. Mal angenommen, wir haben sowas wie "Sport ist/sind Mord und Totschlag". Vom Gefühl her wäre ich bei "ist". Aber wahrscheinlich auch nur, weil die Phrase "Mord und Totschlag" meist als Einheit verwendet wird.

Comment: @HalvarF Noch einmal: Duden Randnummer 1579:  *[Das Tuaregvolk] sind [tüchtige Jäger]. Hier wird genau diese Verwendung als falsch markiert. Es wird ausdrücklich gesagt, dass es sich auf bestimmte Pronomen (das, es, ..) beschränkt, und ansonsten vermieden wird. Demnach ist Ihr Beispiel falsch.

Comment: @OranMatheus OK, ich habe versucht, das noch einzubauen. In 1579 steht "... wird vermieden", da ist "falsch" m.E. das falsche Wort.

Comment: @JohannesR Duden Grammatik (oberstes Zitat) ist da eindeutig, dass es Plural sein muss, auch in RN 1579 mit dem Beispiel "Das Tuaregvolk sind tüchtige Jäger." Ich denke "Mord und Totschlag" ist da als feststehender Begriff tatsächlich eine Ausnahme.

Comment: @HalvarF Ja, da haben Sie recht, es wundert mich dann allerdings, wieso der Duden das Zeichen für "grammatisch inkorrekt" genutzt hat und nicht "unklare Bedeutung", "?". Na, wer weiß...

Answer (score 0):

Der genannte Beispielsatz soll vermutlich ein sogenanntes *Zeugma* darstellen, das ist eine besondere Form der Ellipse (einer "Weglassung"). Dabei werden Verben, die gleich sind, weggelassen.

Hier ist ein klassisches Beispiel:

> Der See kann sich, der Landvogt nicht erbarmen.
> <sub>"Wilhelm Tell", Friedrich Schiller</sub>

Die Bedeutung ist hier: "Der See kann sich erbarmen, der Landvogt aber (- im Gegensatz zum See -) kann sich nicht erbarmen.". Das wiederholte Verb "erbarmen" wird aber weggelassen.

Das Wort "Zeugma" kommt aus dem Altgriechischen und bedeutet "Joch". In ein solches Joch sollten besser nur gleichartige Zugtiere gespannt werden, wenn der Wagen unfallfrei gezogen werden soll und deshalb können auch in einem Zeugma nur gleiche Verben weggelassen werden.

Genau das - nämlich gleich - sind "ist" und "sind" aber nicht, weshalb die Konstruktion hier insgesamt nicht funktioniert. Deshalb richtig:

> Erleben ist unser Denken, sind unsere Gefühle.

Man *kann* tatsächlich auch Verben in ein solches Joch zusammenspannen, die unterschiedliche Bedeutung bei gleicher Schreibung haben (sogenannte *Polysemie*). Meistens wird hier die unmittelbare mit einer übertragenen Bedutung kontrastiert. Solch ein Wortspiel ist genaugenommen ungrammatikalisch, wird aber genutzt, wenn eine satirische bzw. komische Wirkung erzielt werden soll:

> Ich heiße nicht nur Heinz Erhardt, sondern Sie auch herzlich willkommen.
> <sub>Heinz Erhardt</sub>

> Erst schlug er ihm die Nase, danach den Weg nach Hause ein.

Comment: Vielen Dank für die ausführliche Antwort. Das wäre dann natürlich eine Alternative zu meinem Ursprungssatz.